# Why Wordpress doesn't display embedded code properly

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I did copy & paste an embedded code into Wordpress HTML format

```html
<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5jvinv9/n179" frameborder="0" width="113" height="18"></iframe>
```

However, the output is only above link. Please see the attached pictures.

Could anybody tell me why and how to solve it? Thank you very much
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BldPV.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3z1Q.png)
Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

With Wordpress.com, you have to use the "Add Embed" or "Add Media" buttons. From the documentation: "WordPress.com VIP handles embeds and scripts that haven't already been whitelisted above in a special way for security protection. [Here's how to embed](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/embedding-rich-media-from-around-the-web-with-protected-embeds/#scripts-iframes-and-objects) code that begins with script, iframe, object."

Comment: In my wordpress interface doesn't have "Add Embed" button as you can see in my post's pic. Do you mean I have to apply wordpress.com vip is the only way to embed codes?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need VIP. Does [this](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/no-add-media-button-in-my-posts?replies=12) help?